# Anchor Link Issue

Tags: hyperlink, anchor

I wonder if someone could help me troubleshoot some Anchor Link problems. I have 13 shows on the same page similar to the one below where I've created links from Read More and an image called Ticket.jpg. Both links work and go to the correct page location. The problem is that all text in the shows below become active links as well.

This is my problem page:  http://bluefrogstudios.ca//index-copy.html
I've tried everything to correct this without any luck. Excuse my limited html knowledge.

"**TRIOLOGY with Miles Black, Jodi Proznick & Bill Coon"**

#### Saturday Feb.15th, 2014 Doors: 7:00 pm Show 8:00 pm

**Semiahmoo Arts** presents **TRIOLOGY** for another “Live From Blue Frog” concert recording...
            [READ MORE..](/newshows.html#trilogy)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have missed the closing `</a>` tag after a link in your HTML

Line 110:

```
<div class="ticket"><a href="/newshows.html#cuda"><img src="images/Ticket.png" alt="Ticket"></div>
```

Comment: Thats what it was.. Thanks so much